# How to link Slider to GridView.builder?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I link the sliders to the GridView.builder ?
I want it when you move the slider, the pictures are moved and the number of the picture's catalog is written at the bottom as a result!
I tried a lot but I can't link it , The slider value will be (*snapshot.data[i]["photo_cat"],*) photo catalog .

[image]

This is my code

```
Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: FutureBuilder(
                    future: getData(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      
                      return Center(
                        child: GridView.builder(
                          // shrinkWrap: true,

                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisCount: 1,
                            // crossAxisSpacing: 10
                          ),
                          itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () {},
                                child: Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      border: Border.all(
                                          color: Colors.deepPurple.shade500,
                                          width: 2),
                                      borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(35)),
                                      image: DecorationImage(
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        image: NetworkImage(
                                            "http://10.0.2.2/test/upload/" +
                                                snapshot.data[i]["post_image"]),
                                      )),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  height: size.height*0.35 ,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10,),
                Container(
                    color: Colors.greenAccent,
                    height: size.height,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child:Column(
                      children: [
                        Slider(
                          min: 0.0,
                          max: 100.0,
                          value: _value,
                          divisions: 10,
                          label: '${_value.round()}',
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              _value = value;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Age ${_value.round()}',
                          // style: TextStyle(color: _statusColor),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )

                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try [**scroll_to_index**](https://pub.dev/packages/scroll_to_index) to scroll directly to the index you want in your grid :)